# only single uitableview cell will be draggable and reorder

Tags: ios, uitableview

is it possible in uitableview that when tableview enters editing mode only selected cell will be able to reorder and other cells will not be draggable. 
i tried to set all cell's "showsreordercontrol" to NO, and only selected cell's property to YES; but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i achieved it by comparing selected cell's indexpath.row with indexpath.row. in this method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```